# Workflow GCP trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, workflow, execution

I have a workflow that turns on GCP.
I want to trigger my workflow (execute) using a simple click on a url, what solution can i do ?

When i try to  use the Invocation URL (https://workflowexecutions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXX/locations/europe-west1/workflows/XXX/executions) provided by itself i got this error :

{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"method": "google.cloud.workflows.executions.v1.Executions.ListExecutions",
"service": "workflowexecutions.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}

Comment: You must perform an authenticated call. If you have a front end, you should have a backend, and this backend should be in charge to authenticate the user, and to invoke the Workflow execution API.